# Discord.js: hide command input or modifying it before sending (working on a quiz bot)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a quiz bot which is setup in the following way:

User type the answer to my questions using `!q <answer>`. The `<answer>` gets sent to a text channel that only me can see and the `!q` command is delete immediately.
However, I tested with 15+ people and sometime answers were visible, even if briefly.

Now, I give points according to the fastest correct answer, so if you wait to see the correct answer you will get few points, if not none.
Nevertheless, I would like to hide somehow the `<answer>`.

Here are my ideas that I don't know if are possible or how to do them yet:

1) hide the command `!q`: the bot will get it but it is not shown in chat

2) store the command `!q`, store the `<answer>`, change the `<answer>` then send it to chat (I will get the non-changed answer)

3) I am aware of the fact that I could create a channel for each player, but it will be long to setup. It is a solution, but I would like to try other option before this one.

This is my progress so far:

```js
client.on('message', msg => {

  let args = msg.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

  switch (args[0]){
    case 'q':
      msg.delete();
        msg.reply(":star: Risposta inviata!"); //Answer sent!
        client.channels.get("<channel id>").send(msg.author + " " + args[1]); //where args[1] is the answer given
        break;
  }
});
```

Thank you for your help and ideas!
Have a nice Sunday

Comment: You have to show what you tried to get this to work

Comment: Are you getting any errors? `msg.delete()` should work

Comment: No no, I m not getting any error. The script works.
I'm trying to see if there are other ways to accomplish my goal, which is users typing questions and not be able to see other people answers.

Comment: You'd have to get the users to DM the answer to the bot. assign an ID to the question so you can have multiple quizzes at once, you can then have users DM the bot `!q <question ID> <answer>

Comment: I like this idea, I will explore it. So, technically, the bot could send all the answer to my private channel (so I can assign points, as the quiz is live). The workflow for this idea could be: players DM answer to bot > bot send the answer to my private text channel

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the speed of the connection from wherever you're hosting your bot and the current ping of the Discord API how long a message takes to delete. You could try to only accept commands in PMs, so if someone wanted to submit an answer, they would have to PM the bot, which means nobody would be able to see their answer.
You cannot modify a users message though, so deleting them or PM commands are the only things I can think of.